# Or condition for literal string in regex expression

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have the following regex expression

```
re.findall('\(([0-9].*?)\)', a[a.find('('):].strip())
```

defined for strings like

```
asdasdasd (21345-asdasdasd)
```

to retrieve what is inside parenthesis followed by a number. But I also want to be capable to retrieve what is inside followed by 'NA' string, like:

```
asdasdasd (NA-asdasdasd)
```

I've tried:

```
re.findall('\(([0-9].*?)\)|\((NA.*?)\)', a[a.find('('):].strip())
```

but produces a tuple. How would it be? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try `\((?:\d|NA)[^()]*\)`

Comment: So, remove the capturing parentheses. Or use `re.findall(r'\(((?:[0-9]+|NA)-[^)]*)\)', a)`

Comment: Hello @WiktorStribiżew it worked!

Comment: Hello @revo it also works but removing outsider parenthesis, just`'(?:\d|NA)[^()]*'`

Comment: Yes but then it may match similar sub-strings that are not enclosed in parentheses. It depends on what you desire.

Answer (score 0):

You may capture the substring between parentheses when the text inside starts with digits / `NA` followed with `-` and any other chars other than `(` and `)` using

```
re.findall(r'\(((?:[0-9]+|NA)-[^)]*)\)', a)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vgjwEV/1).

**Details**

- `\(` - a `(`
- `((?:[0-9]+|NA)-[^)]*)` - Capturing group (this value will be returned by `re.findall`):

  - `(?:[0-9]+|NA)` - 1 or more digits or `NA`
  - `-`  - a hyphen
  - `[^)]*` - 0+ chars other than `)`
- `\)`  - a `)` char.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/U4FfWX):

```
import re
strs = ['asdasdasd (21345-asdasdasd)', 'asdasdasd (NA-asdasdasd)']
for s in strs:
    print(re.findall(r'\(((?:[0-9]+|NA)-[^)]*)\)', s))
```

Output:

```
['21345-asdasdasd']
['NA-asdasdasd']
```